# Fast shortcut/way to matrices

Tags: math-mode, environments, matrices

I started to TeX my lectures instead of writing them on a paper, usually this is not a big problem. I can handle most of the formulas in little time.

The only problem I have is to write down matrices.
Time spent by the docent to write down a matrix is nearly nil compared to the time I spent typing in:  `\begin{p` + <kbd>Tab</kbd> +  <kbd>Enter</kbd> .

If it would be one or two matrices I could keep up easily.

But the problem with studying mathematics is that if there is one matrix, there are usually a bunch of them following it.

I could try to learn enough TeX Syntax to build this command myself, but as the docent needs nil time writing down a matrix, my free-time as a math-student in the 4th semester is convergent to the same value.

---

For the tl;dr part of the community

Could somebody help me out building a new shorter command for matrices in a math-environment.

If somebody finds the time to help out.
Thanks

Comment: Which editor do you use?

Comment: You should consider writing the matrix in Excel and then export it to LaTeX using [Excel2LaTeX](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/excel2latex).

Comment: how short do you want? you only have to use a single character `&` between cells and two characters `\\ ` between rows it's hard to get a lot more compact than this

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The problem is not the size of the matrix, but the amount of times I have to write "\begin{pm" what might not seems much, but will add up if you have to write it often enough.

Comment: @Mico At the moment TeX-Studio, but I am not really bound to it. Since I mostly don't have the time to use the GUI anyways, I am not really bound to any editor, so if you have a good hint what to use, I would love it. I am thankful for every second.

Comment: any editor ought to be able to be customised to add that as a single keystroke, but if you want to do it in tex then `\newcommand\m[1]{\begin{pmatrix}#1\end{pmatrix}}` then `\m{a&b&c\\x&y&z}`

Comment: @Werner I am not sure, if this would spare me time in the first place, but I might give it a try.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle could you write it down as answer, so I could upvote and accept it. Really appreciated!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Any editor ought to be able to be customised to add any text such `\begin{pmatrix}  \end{pmatrix}` as a single keystroke, but if you want to do it in tex then

```
\newcommand\m[1]{\begin{pmatrix}#1\end{pmatrix}}
```

then

```
\m{a&b&c\\x&y&z}
```

will make a 2 row, 3 column matrix (2,3).

Comment: Did you mean a 2x3 matrix?